# Is it possible to override __setattr__ for a class?

Tags: python

In Python, I know it's possible to say something like

```
>>> class C:
...   def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...     print("Hey, you can't set {0} to {1}!".format(name, value))
...
>>> x = C()
>>> x.y = 5
Hey, you can't set y to 5!
```

But the following still works:

```
>>> C.y = 5
>>> print(C.y)
5
```

Is it possible to get functionality like:

```
>>> C.y = 5
Hey, you can't set y to 5!
```

Asking solely out of curiosity, as I can't really think of an example where that'd be genuinely practical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like all special methods, [`__setattr__` is accessed **on the type**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup); for instances that is the class, for classes, that is the *metaclass*.

You'll have to define it on a custom metaclass instead of directly on the class itself:

```
class SetAttrMeta(type):
    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        print("Hey, you can't set {0} to {1}!".format(name, value))

class C(metaclass=SetAttrMeta):
    pass
```

Python then looks up `__setattr__` on the return value of `type(C)`, which here is `SetAttrMeta`.

Demo:

```
>>> class SetAttrMeta(type):
...     def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
...         print("Hey, you can't set {0} to {1}!".format(name, value))
... 
>>> class C(metaclass=SetAttrMeta):
...     pass
... 
>>> C.spam = 'eggs'
Hey, you can't set spam to eggs!
```

Comment: For python 2: `class C(object): __metaclass__ = SetAttrMeta`

Comment: @MartinKonecny: yup, the `object` is crucial there, metaclasses only work for new-style classes.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters why does ` C = SetAttrMeta("C",(),{})` work if you need to use  object?

Comment: Because metaclasses can *only* produce new-style classes. The `object` baseclass is implicit in that case (just like it is on Python 3).